# html2canvas not display all div as jpeg

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I use htmlCanvas in angular to make div as jpeg and display it.
What happens is that the jpeg display only the part of the div that I see , as a printScreen.
The JS:

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            html2canvas($("#widget"), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                    // Convert and download as image 
                    Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(canvas);
                     $("#img-out").append(canvas);

                    //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi can you please create fiddle for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the code as below

```
  $("#img-out").append(Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(canvas));
```

You are using Save as function and still use the old canvas object.